# nested where query in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

i have a class like this

```
public class Survey
    {
        public Survey()
        {
            SurveyResponses=new List<SurveyResponse>();
        }

        public Guid SurveyId { get; set; }

        public string SurveyName { get; set; }

        public string SurveyDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SurveyResponse> SurveyResponses { get; set; }
    }
```

and a Question class like this

```
 public class Question
    {

        public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }

        public string QuestionText { get; set; }

        public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }

        public bool IsOtherAllowed { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    }
```

i want to write a query to select a survey which contains a particular question

something along these lines

```
 Survey s1 = db.Surveys.Where(s => s.Questions.Where(q => q.QuestionId == "1eb56610-853d-4a9e-adc7-e0ec069390b7"));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Survey s1 = db.Surveys
    .Where(s => s.Questions.Any(q => q.QuestionId == "1eb56610-853d-4a9e-adc7-e0ec069390b7"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you fabiano...do u know any good tutorial for building such lamda expressions

Comment: I would read the msdn articles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx and take a look at the available extension methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx. Or just google for some tutorials. also note that not all LINQ extensions are available in Linq to Entities: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx